# Switching from gfortan to ifort using MPI

Tags: fortran, mpi, intel

I have written a code in fortran using MPI for parallelization and I always used gfortran as a compiler, but now I want to go with Intel ifort. The problem is that on the server I try to run it for mpif90 the gnu compiler is set as default:

```
mpif90 --showme
gfortran -I/usr/lib/openmpi/include -pthread -I/usr/lib/openmpi/lib -L/usr//lib -L/usr/lib/openmpi/lib -lmpi_f90 -lmpi_f77 -lmpi -ldl -lhwloc
```

I have no idea what flags I have to include with ifort. I tried it like that:

```
ifort -openmp test_mpi.f -I/usr/local/openmpi-1.8.4-intel/include -I/usr/local/openmpi-1.8.4-intel/lib -L/usr/local/openmpi-1.8.4-intel/lib -lmpi_f90 -lmpi_f77 -lmpi
```

Which gives me to output:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../lib//libmpi_f77.so: undefined reference to `opal_uses_threads'
```

Than I tried using not the Intel OpenMpi but the /usr/lib/openmpi/, than the program compiles but when executing it I get:

```
./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libiomp5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Which is wired because looking up echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

```
/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.5.192/compiler/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.5.192/mpirt/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.5.192/ipp/../compiler/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.5.192/ipp/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.5.192/compiler/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.5.192/mkl/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.5.192/tbb/lib/intel64/gcc4.4
```

and in /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.5.192/compiler/lib/intel64 there is "libiomp5.so".

Has anyone an idea how to fix my compiler flags?

@HighPerformanceMark:
I did that now with:

```
ifort -openmp test_mpi.f -I/opt/intel/mpi-rt/4.1.0/include -I/opt/intel/mpi-rt/4.1.0/lib -L/opt/intel/mpi-rt/4.1.0/lib -lmpi_f90 -lmpi_f77 -lmpi
```

which gave me:

```
ld: skipping incompatible /opt/intel/mpi-rt/4.1.0/lib/libmpi.so when searching for -lmpi ld: skipping incompatible /opt/intel/mpi-rt/4.1.0/lib/libmpi.a when searching for -lmpi
```

By skipping `-lmpi` the error:

```
include -I/opt/intel/mpi-rt/4.1.0/lib -L/opt/intel/mpi-rt/4.1.0/lib -lmpi_f90 -lmpi_f77 ld: /tmp/ifort41PQRn.o: undefined reference to symbol 'mpi_null_delete_fn_' ld: note: 'mpi_null_delete_fn_' is defined in DSO /usr/lib/libmpi.so.1 so try adding it to the linker command line /usr/lib/libmpi.so.1: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
```

appeared!

Comment: You need to set the compiler variables first. Intel provides a script for that task: `. <path to ifort installation>/bin/compilervars.sh intel64`. Then all libraries should be found and the code will compile...

Comment: @AlexanderVogt: Sorry I got it now! I did: `. /opt/intel/composer_xe_2015.1.133/bin/compilervars. 'intel64'` which worked. I compiled it with: `ifort -openmp test_mpi.f -I/usr/lib/openmpi/include -I/usr/lib/openmpi/lib -L/usr/lib/openmpi/lib -lmpi_f90 -lmpi_f77 -lmpi` which again gave me: `./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libiomp5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` when I executed it.

Comment: I would reommend asking your HPC system admin if they support choosing ompilers and mpi versions using modules. That is much simpler.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark and Vladimir: I did both and I got it running! The problem was that $PATH and $LD_LIBRARY_PATH did not point to the Intel complier. Thanks

Comment: You should always use the MPI library installed for or compiled with the respective compiler. Usually, the libraries in `/usr/lib` are compiled with `gcc` and *might* be incompatible with the Intel compilers. You should ask your system administrator, which version to use (as @VladimirF pointed out, preferably with the module system).

Comment: Thanks @Stefan! I just did that and the system administrator gave me different possibilities what MPI version works with what version of ifort!